# Asp / C# .Net Entity Framework - Create Extended Parameterized Query based on Conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

In ADO.Net I created a DAL file that took parameters from the user and if they were not null, the query got extended based on if statements. Now I want to do the same in Entity Framework.
I have searched a number of sites including Stack Overflow but failed to get my satisfactory answer.
for Reference, the following link also could not help me

[Select Query with Where condition depending on list values in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461767/select-query-with-where-condition-depending-on-list-values-in-asp-net)

the required scenario is

```
cmd.text = "SELECT FROM tbl_name WHERE id>0 "

if(param_value != null)
{
    cmd.text += " AND (param_name = '@param_value')";
    if(!cmd.contains("param_name"))
          cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("param_name", @param_value);
    cmd.parameters["param_name"] = @param_value;
}

// proceed further with cmd.text
```

please ignore the syntax right now, I just wanted to convey my concept of what I want to do.

I want to apply the same concept for Entity Framework

---

Well two days back I found a scenerio in wheich the query (text) was built in an aspx.cs file and it was passed as it is to a custom built function in DAL which passed the text to cmd.text and processed the rest of retrieval in an ADO.net style.

This method is potentially dangerious as anyone with a bit knowlege can break this security down to grounds.
I want to create a query that has parameters as well as its vales like I have shown in above code block.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Comment: then please tell me any alternative solutions for the sake so that I could perform my custom selections.

Comment: @GulabMehak Please, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233461/dynamic-conditions-in-linq-to-entities-query and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122220/dynamic-where-clause-in-linq-to-entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out working with Entity framework is a totally different world that classic approach. In here, we work with models/objects and their relationships with each other and we access them based on that relationship. So to answer the question we need to get that model first like

```
Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
```

and than from that, we get a model object which does have different properties in it like title, IMDb, rating etc.
We get them repeatedly using where clause as below:

```
db.Where(movies=>movies.IMDb==10).Where(movies=>movies.title=="The Game Plan")
```

this all is equal to the following in classic approach

```
AND (IMDb = 10) AND (title = 'The Game Plan')
```

following that, one can extend his query as much as he likes.
Again ignore the syntax here because I am here t convey the idea only.

For reference, the following links might be helpful keeping in mind the context i have explained.

[Multiple where conditions in EF - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353350/multiple-where-conditions-in-ef)

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ-to-SQL:

```
var param_value = 0;
db.tbl_name.Where(x => x.id > 0).Where(x => x.some_property == param_value).ToString();
```

If you look at the generated SQL, you'll see that's its parameterized (it picks the `param_name`s, though).

I added the `ToString()` at the end, just so you could see the resulting SQL; based on OP, I'd say to leave this off, and keep modifying the query further directly in LINQ, rather than converting to SQL as a string and concatenating.